# JQuery not working in .html file

Tags: jquery, html

I have a .html with the following code inside:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "test"></div>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/"></a>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#test").click(function(){
            alert("works");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I run the program and click on "#test" nothing happens.
Am I doing something wrong?

Side note: I am using Sublime Text 2

Comment: have you added jQuery source file in head element?

Comment: have you checked the mentioned path of the Jquery file is correct.?

Comment: for testing use a cdn version of jQuery `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: How can you click on "#test" when there's nothing in the div? I mean, you sure you're clicking in the right place? :)

Comment: your div - #test is empty ? how it is possible to click it ?

Comment: Yes, I have css... just not mention @DavidKhaykin

Comment: you said, you have css, but there is no css linked.

Comment: All works fine, check http://jsfiddle.net/7j4HQ/ this demo

Comment: Got it...Most likely thing here is your script source of "jquery.js" is a broken link. Check the developer console and see if there is a JS error "$ is undefined" and that will give you a hint that jQuery isn't being loaded. One of these answers that uses CDN link should do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

You just try it with jquery CDN

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#test").click(function(){
alert("works");
});
</script>
```

This may helps you

Answer (score 0):

First check your Jquery path is correct

```
 <script src="check_your_path/jquery.js"></script>

<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#test").click(function(){
 alert("works");

 });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

-first you check given path of jquery file is correct or not
-Second your div is empty so put something in

```
 <div id="test"> Click Me </div>
```

now it work perfect

this is my code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="test">click me</div>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/"></a>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script>
        $("#test").click(function(){
            alert("works");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and Dude always put your include file like js,css in the `<head></head>`
so correct structure is

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
 <script>
            $("#test").click(function(){
                alert("works");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id ="test">click me</div>
        <a href="http://jquery.com/"></a>


    </body>
    </html>
```